# Kotlin MultiPlatform - Publish Android Library Failing

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

Im trying to publish an Android library (debug/release) with the new Kotlin MultiPlatform set up. Im successfully able to publish iOS frameworks, but not android libraries. This is the error I end up getting:

A problem occurred configuring project ':shared'.

> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Kotlin target 'android' tried to set up publishing for Android build variants that are not library variants or do not exist:
> * release
> * debug
> Check the 'publishLibraryVariants' property, it should point to existing Android library variants. Publishing of application and test variants is not supported.

However, I can clearly see the variants in my Android Studio. Im also able to run the Android/IOS app from Android Studio using the library dependecy as a project dependency
`implementation(project(":shared"))`

Only facing problems when trying to publish it.

This is my build.gradle.kts:

````
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlin-android-extensions")
    id("com.squareup.sqldelight")
    id("dev.icerock.mobile.multiplatform-resources")
    `maven-publish`
}

group = "com.sekhar.testkmp"
version = "0.1"
val coroutinesVersion = "1.3.9-native-mt"
val serializationVersion = "1.0.0-RC"
val ktorVersion = "1.4.0"
val sqlDelightVersion: String by project

repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    android {
        publishLibraryVariants("release", "debug")
    }
    ios {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "shared"
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutinesVersion")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:$serializationVersion")

                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktorVersion")

                implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:runtime:$sqlDelightVersion")
                implementation("dev.icerock.moko:resources:0.13.1")
                implementation("dev.icerock.moko:parcelize:0.4.0")
                implementation("dev.icerock.moko:graphics:0.4.0")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1")

                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:android-driver:$sqlDelightVersion")
            }
        }
        val androidTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
                implementation("junit:junit:4.12")
            }
        }
        val iosMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("com.squareup.sqldelight:native-driver:$sqlDelightVersion")
            }
        }
        val iosTest by getting
    }
}

dependencies {
    commonMainApi("dev.icerock.moko:resources:0.13.1")
}

multiplatformResources {
    multiplatformResourcesPackage = "com.sekhar.testkmp" // required
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion(29)
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(24)
        targetSdkVersion(29)
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
        getByName("debug") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        isAbortOnError = false
    }
}

val packForXcode by tasks.creating(Sync::class) {
    group = "build"
    val mode = System.getenv("CONFIGURATION") ?: "DEBUG"
    val sdkName = System.getenv("SDK_NAME") ?: "iphonesimulator"
    val targetName = "ios" + if (sdkName.startsWith("iphoneos")) "Arm64" else "X64"
    val framework = kotlin.targets.getByName<KotlinNativeTarget>(targetName).binaries.getFramework(mode)
    inputs.property("mode", mode)
    dependsOn(framework.linkTask)
    val targetDir = File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
    from({ framework.outputDirectory })
    into(targetDir)
}

tasks.getByName("build").dependsOn(packForXcode)```
````

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most common solution to this is to apply the `android` plugin: `id("com.android.library")` before the `kotlin` multiplatform plugin: `kotlin("multiplatform")`.

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization")
    id("kotlin-android-extensions")
    id("com.squareup.sqldelight")
    id("dev.icerock.mobile.multiplatform-resources")
    `maven-publish`
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This fixed it.

Comment: @dazza5000 can you explain why this works?

Comment: No. My guess is that each plugin modifies the gradle task graph and the order in which the tree is modified is important.

Comment: someone else also encountered the same workaround:  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-34038/With-kotlin.mpp.enableGranularSourceSetsMetadatatrue-Android-lib-variants-arent-published-from-a-multiplatform-lib#focus=Comments-27-3712967.0-0